# While Loop using PHP with a MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, while-loop

I have a database (SQL) with the table "Staff" with two records in it. I am required to display the contents of these records on a web page using PHP.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>CES Staff details</title>
</head>

<body>

**code emitted**

<?php
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ; 
$looping = 1;
$i = $row.length;
while ($looping <= $i)  
    {
        echo $row["Name"].", Room ".$row["Room"].", Tel ".$row["Telephone"] ;
        $looping++;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I change the while loop correctly so that it will display both records on the page.

Thanks!

Comment: `$row.length` is not valid PHP.

Comment: What is it displaying right now?

Comment: Nothing, but removing the while loop would display the first record.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array()` only retrieves a single row from the database.  You need to call it inside your `while` loop to retrieve all rows.  The `$looping` increment is unnecessary here, since `mysql_fetch_array()` returns false when no more rows are available.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{
    echo $row["Name"].", Room ".$row["Room"].", Tel ".$row["Telephone"] ;
}
```

Comment: NOTE: 'mysql_fetch_array' was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. PHP 5.x is also deprecated; so, this method should no longer be used.

Answer (score 2):

I'll do...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   // print $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  
    {
        echo $row["Name"].", Room ".$row["Room"].", Tel ".$row["Telephone"] ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$qry = mysql_query($result); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))  
    {
        echo $row["Name"].", Room ".$row["Room"].", Tel ".$row["Telephone"] ;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has great documentation with examples. Check out the example for [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row["Name"].", Room ".$row["Room"].", Tel ".$row["Telephone"] ;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   echo $row["Name"].", Room ".$row["Room"].", Tel ".$row["Telephone"] ; 
}
```

In php there is no such thing like $row.length; the "." is an operator for string concatenation. Read more on mysql_fetch_array at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo $row["Name"].", Room ".$row["Room"].", Tel ".$row["Telephone"] ;
  }
?>
```

Comment: mysql and mysqli both are different. You are correct if he was using mysqli instead of mysql :)