# Choose a part of the data from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have posted a code I am working on and the result in array.
please tell me how to choose only a part of the result from that array ?
code

```
$sql = 'SELECT status, phone, COUNT(*) AS count FROM people WHERE phone=9876543210 GROUP BY phone, status';
  if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    print_r(array_count_values($row));
         }
```

Result

```
Array ( [1] => 2 [9876543210] => 2 [14] => 2 ) Array ( [2] => 2 [9876543210] => 2 [10] => 2 ) Array ( [3] => 2 [9876543210] => 2 [5] => 2 ) Array ( [4] => 2 [9876543210] => 2 [1] => 2 )
```

How to choose and display only the number 14?
or only the number 5?
I want to ad the number 14 to a $value.
like `echo $value;` should result the number 14.
Update: I am not trying just to filter the results from the database, the usage is to count certain values.
I wan to display like "14 of your orders are approved, 5 of them cancelled, etc.."

Answer (score 0):

Why simple don't use echo like:

```
echo $row['nameofdbvalue'];
```

Try to see that SO topic : [SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395941/while-loop-using-php-with-a-mysql-server)

---

For answer at your comment:

If your database is for example:

```
id - name
1  - Jason
2  - Micheal
```

You query with a simple select and fetch result like:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      echo $row['name'];
    }
  }
}
```

This code will print Jason and Micheal.

if you want only one of that you can change your query with `WHERE id='1'`
and echo will output only Jason

---

you need to fetch row like that so:

```
$sql = "select count(*) from table limit 100";
$count = $mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_row()[0];
echo $count;
```

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt understand, can you show an example ?

Comment: thanks for the reply. But u misunderstood, because I was not very clear with my question. I am not looking for a way to filter my database results, I have already done that and got results, now I want to show the count of that results. these counts are displaying in array.

Comment: i change again!

Comment: thanks for the time, but this wont work for me.  but I am looking for help with "foreach".